# Посимвольное сравнение

Tags: java, char

Есть, допустим, такой код:

```
String m = "1101101";
    boolean[] check = new boolean[7];
    conversion(m, check);
    for(boolean v : check){
        System.out.println(v);
    }


public void conversion(String days, boolean[] checkDays){
    for(int i = 0; i < days.toCharArray().length; i++){
        char p = days.toCharArray()[i];
        System.out.println(p);
        if(days.toCharArray()[i] == '1'){
            checkDays[i] = true;
        }
        else {
            checkDays[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

sout(p) выводит всё верно:"1101101", а sout(v) выводит всегда "false". Я так понял, что ошибка в сравнении, может на поверхности лежит, но заметить не могу.

Comment: Что такое `sout(p)` и `sout(v)`?

Comment: @s8am,  System.out.println(p) и  System.out.println(v)

Comment: У меня данный метод работает корректно. Покажите **весь** Ваш код.

Comment: После `boolean[] check = new boolean[7];` – каждый из элементов массива `check` имеет значение `false`. Думаю, у Вас они и не меняются.

Comment: @s8am, 160 строк? У меня более нигде не используются ни этот метод, ни переменные. Я вроде сам смотрю и понимаю, что всё должно работать, но как будто отказывается сравнивать  `== '1'` и сразу уходит на `else`

Comment: @s8am, после объявления массива `check` написал `check[2] = true;`, всё равно после запуска все элементы `false`, значит срабатывает `else` в методе

Comment: Поставьте `brakepoint` в методе `conversion` и убедить в корректности его работы: массив `checkDays` заполняется в соответствии с требуемым алгоритмом. Ищите проблему в другом.

Comment: @s8am, спасибо решил проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась странным образом. Во время дебага, почему то увидел в консоли массив, который я удалил давным давно (не понимаю, что он там делал, т.к. в коде его уже не было). После этого, т.к. я дебажил через телефон, снёс приложение, запустил заново, и всё заработало.

P.S. Писал в Android Studio

Comment: Скорее всего у вас просто не отключена функция InstantRun в студии

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а где её отключить?

Comment: В настройках, build/execution что-то там -> InstantRun